# Can home directory be duplicated in linux?

Tags: linux, home-directory

In my CentOS, root's home directory is '/' and apache's home directory is '/var/www'. But I want those users to use same home directory (wherever it would be).
Is it okay to use same home directory by several users?
If so, sometimes, when some file is created in their home directory automatically, each user will create same file in their same home directory. Then would it make a conflict?

(sorry for my English, it's not my native language.)

Comment: You are very likely to run into permissions issues if you attempt this (e.g. one user will create a preference file, it will be owned by them and only readable/writable by them - not the other users). I wouldn't recommend trying this.

Comment: Yes. But I don't think it is a great idea. Better to add each user to the same group and add a soft-link in the home directories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this.  You would have to put the users in the same group and ensure the home directory belonged to the group.  Then you set group permissions for that folder.

However, I'm not sure why you'd want to this.  As stated earlier, you might symlink to a common directory.  Making Apache's home directory the root folder of your machine doesn't sound wise if it's public facing.  If it's not or you don't care about this machine, then, by all means do it.